# BeautifulSoup returning different HTML for the pages that seems to have same HTML structure

Tags: python, web-crawler, screen-scraping, webautomation

I'm trying to scrape customer reviews from Amazon.com.

The thing is, BeautifulSoup is returning different HTML for different pages.

Because of this, I could only collect the reviews from the first page.

For example, I can bring the whole html from the first review page, and collect the reviews.
(https://www.amazon.com/Renewed-Apple-Model-Wi-Fi-9-7in/product-reviews/B07D3DDJ4L/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1)

but not from the later pages. It returns HTML that looks completely different from the first page one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import re
from collections import namedtuple
import time

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
                    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                    'Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'),
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'
}

response = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/Renewed-Apple-Model-Wi-Fi-9-7in/product-reviews/B07D3DDJ4L/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=2", headers=HEADERS).content

# html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

reviews = []

review_list = soup.find('div', {'id': 'cm_cr-review_list' })
product_reviews = review_list.find_all('div', {'data-hook': 'review'})
```

```
review_list = soup.find('div', {'id': 'cm_cr-review_list' })
product_reviews = review_list.find_all('div', {'data-hook': 'review'})

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Does anyone know why am I getting different results for different pages?
I don't understand why it's returning totally different results when I just changed the page number.

Comment: Have you checked your reponse for some hints? Also take a closer look to your browsers dev tools and its XHR tab if you page the results.